# How to get access token using oauth2 for Github api using python

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, github-api

I am building an app to access Github api in python using django. I am new to this building this kind of app for the first time. 
I specified an link to get the access of a user's account like this

```
<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=something&scope=something,something"></a>
```

Now I can access the user's account. Now the problem is, I want to use oauth2 so that it doesn't ask for username and password for each request. 
my question is how to get the access_token and where to store it. How to pass post parameter of `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` such as `client_id, scope, code` in my django view. And how to link different access for different user. Please help me. I am having problem in getting the basics right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [Python Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) and then leveraging their [Github backend](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/github.html) after setting it up to [work with your django app](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html).

So, you would roughly be able to pass the access token using something like:

```
import requests

user = User.objects.get(...)
social = user.social_auth.get(provider='github')
response = requests.get(
   'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize? 
    client_id=something&scope=something,something',
    params={'access_token': social.extra_data['access_token']}
)
retrieved_data = response.json()['items']
```

You can also make the token available in your template if you'd like to continue using a link. And, you don't need to pass the scope as a query parameter, certainly, Python Social Auth can also handle that for you